# Windows Azure Storage table can't connect, but blob is ok

Tags: azure, storage

I can't connect table, but connect blob is ok.

Here is my code:

```
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("tableStorage"));

        audioBlob = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        bool y = audioBlob.Exists();

        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        submitInfoTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");
        bool x = submitInfoTable.Exists();
```

I debug it, `y` is `true`.
But when it run to `bool x = submitInfoTable.Exists();`, I am waiting long time and it is no response.

Anyone know how to solve it? Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks OK to me. If you're connecting to storage emulator, can you please ensure that table service is running in the emulator?

[image]

Comment: and that port 10002 is not being used by some torrent client.